# start php5.5.38 fail over in mac os sierra

Tags: php

I'm update mac os to sierra version and  restart system, but start php-fpm and `php -v`  show error message example:

```
./php55-fpm start
-n Starting php-fpm
php-fpm(69933,0x7fffdac9b3c0) malloc: *** malloc_zone_unregister() failed for 0x7fffdac91000
./php55-fpm: line 53: 69933 Illegal instruction: 4  $php_fpm_BIN --daemonize $php_opts
 failed
```

How to solve it?

my php version is 5.5.38

Comment: Does PHP 5.5 support Mac OS Sierra? I doubt.

Comment: me too, Im after upgrade php 5.6 or 7 version , is working。

Comment: Very useful information to confirm that PHP 5.5 is incompatible with Mac OS Sierra.